# jQuery multiple replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove the euro sign from my string.

Since the string looks like this €33.0000 - €37.5000, I first explode to string on the - after I try to remove the euro sign.

```
var string = jQuery('#amount').val();
var arr = string.split(' - ');

if(arr[0] == arr[1]){
    jQuery(this).find('.last').css("display", "none");
}else{
    for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
        arr[i].replace('€','');
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

When I try it on my site, the euro signs aren't removed, when I get the string like this

```
var string = jQuery('#amount').val().replace("€", "");
```

Only the first euro sign is removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.replace()` replace only the fisrt occurence with a string, and replace all occurences with a RegExp:

```
jQuery('#amount').val().replace(/€/g, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regular expression with global replace flag:

```
"€33.0000 - €37.5000".replace(/€/g,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

First get rid of the € (Globally), than split the string into Array parts

```
var noeur = str.replace(/€/g, '');
var parts = noeur.split(" - ");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your first attempt is that the [`replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) returns a new string. It does not alter the one it executes on.

So it should be `arr[i] = arr[i].replace('€','');`

Also the `replace` method, by default, replaces the 1st occurrence only.

You can use the regular expression support and pass the global modifier `g` so that it applies to the whole string

```
var string = Query('#amount').val().replace(/€/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parts = /^€([0-9.]+) - €([0-9.]+)$/.exec(jQuery('#amount').val()), val1, val2;
if (parts) {
    val1 = parts[1];
    val2 = parts[2];
} else {
    // there is an error in your string
}
```

You can also tolerate spaces here and there: `/^\s*€\s*([0-9.]+)\s*-\s*€\s*([0-9.]+)\s*$/`